# Why won't svg show up in anki flashcard

Tags: javascript, html, anki

I'm trying to get an svg element from a website (jisho.org) and display it on an Anki flashcard

The svg I want is the stroke order diagram. It isn't a link to somewhere, it's directly in the html.

I'm not the best at js so here's what chatGPT came up with (I edited it a bit):

```
{{FrontSide}}
<hr id=answer>
On: {{Onyomi}}
<br>
Kun: {{Kunyomi}}
<br>
{{Definition}}
<br>
<div id="kanji-container"></div>

<script>
var corsProxyUrl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
var jishoUrl = "https://jisho.org/search/{{Kanji}}%23kanji";
var url = corsProxyUrl + jishoUrl;

fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => {
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data, 'text/html');
    var svgElement = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName('stroke_order_diagram--outer_container')[0].firstElementChild;
  
    if (svgElement) {
      var svgHtml = svgElement.outerHTML;
      document.getElementById('kanji-container').innerHTML = svgHtml;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('kanji-container').innerHTML = "No SVG found.";
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
document.getElementById('kanji-container').innerHTML = "Error fetching SVG: " + error;
  });
</script>
```

Anki replaces anything in double curly brackets with whatever's there in the field for the flashcard, for testing purposes you could replace {{Kanji}} in the link with 字.

This doesn't give an error, but it also doesnt display the svg (after activating the cors-anywhere demo)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.